# How is it seen that the solution to Laplace's eq. belongs to $C^2(\Omega) \cap C(\bar{\Omega})$?

Tags: partial-differential-equations

How is it seen that the solution to Laplace's eq. belongs to $C^2(\Omega) \cap C(\bar{\Omega})$?

Or also, if it applies to other PDEs than the Laplace's eq. as well.

Comment: It is not seen, it is *required* to be so. Remember that when formulating a PDE problem we always look for solutions in some space, and in the case of the classical Dirichlet problem this is the space where you *look* for solutions. Or are you working with Sobolev spaces, or spaces of distributions?

Comment: @AlexM. Then how does one know that there even exists a solution $u \in C^2(\Omega) \cap C(\bar{\Omega})$?

Comment: A priori, one doesn't. There is a lot of heavy mathematical machinery used in order to show that it does (and, in fact, this is the whole point of the Dirichlet problem). Unfortunately, this would take a whole lecture, so I cannot even summarize it here.